# Reverse storyboard's animation on click event

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, storyboard

I have a range control and its sequence of actions are contained in a storyboard. I create a sequence of movement but I want to reverse the animation when the user click the reverse button. I have a pause button too and it works OK.

[image: Screenshot of control]

Play button code:

```
public void Animate(DateTime endDate)
{
    previousMaxValue = (DateTime)rangeControl.SelectionRangeEnd;
    previousMinValue = (DateTime)rangeControl.SelectionRangeStart;
    double toValue = (endDate - previousMaxValue).TotalSeconds;
    TimeSpan sp = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(diffInSeconds);
    animation = new DoubleAnimation(0, toValue, new Duration(sp));

    storyboard.Children.Clear();
    storyboard.Children.Add(animation);
    storyboard.AutoReverse = true;
    Storyboard.SetTarget(animation, this);
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation, new PropertyPath(AxisRangeAnimator.ValueProperty));
    storyboard.Begin();
}
```

Pause button code:

```
public void Pause()
{
    storyboard.Pause();
}
```

I'm trying to set the reverse button. The property `storyboard.AutoReverse` makes that the animation go in reverse when it ends, but I want to achieve this effect when the user clicks the button wherever the animation is.

Comment: Have you tried cancelling the animation and starting one that does the exact opposite?

Comment: I will try this too.. I supose that I need the actual position of the Storyboard and set the time at the elapsed time of the actual animation

Comment: Just have the forward animation and the backwards animation from the end to start, then you can use HandoffBehavior.Compose so the 2 animations are merged and the original position is restored when ever you apply the 2nd animation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method StoryBoard.Seek seeks the Storyboard to a new position when the next clock tick occurs.

```
public void Reverse()
{
    TimeSpan CurrentTime = (TimeSpan)storyboard.GetCurrentTime();
    TimeSpan sp = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(diffInSeconds);
    TimeSpan SubtractTime = sp.Subtract(CurrentTime);
    storyboard.Seek(SubtractTime, TimeSeekOrigin.Duration);
}
```